# Comparing HTML from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, http

I am looking to right a little program that will make a httpRequest and get the HTML response of a webpage on an interval and see if there are any changes on the page.  Here is what I have but the issue i have is that it always comes back that the result is different.

```
class Program
{
    private static string sourceText;
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetTimer();

        Console.WriteLine("Program starting");
        Console.ReadLine();

        aTimer.Stop();
        aTimer.Dispose();
    }

    private static void SetTimer()
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string newSourceText;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader source2 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                newSourceText = source2.ReadToEnd();
            }                    
        }


        Console.WriteLine("New Interval");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceText))
        {
            sourceText = newSourceText;
            Console.WriteLine("SourceText replaced");
        }
        else
        {
            if(sourceText == newSourceText)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Results the same");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Results Different!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

im looking for a quick and performant way to do this.

Comment: When you compare them, what's the difference? I would imagine that there's some unique value in the response, maybe a CSRF token, maybe the current date to display, or maybe an ad ID or something. Once you identify this, you'd have to write the code to ignore it.

Comment: Thats my big question... is there a way to parse HTML for specific blocks like targeting the body or a specific element and compairing those together